# Woocommerce Attributes Link

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i would to modify the single product page in my shop site.
I have to remove links from attribute list in the Additional Information Tab.

I found this html is called in this page: /woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php

In this part of code:

```
<td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></td>
```

Do you know if exist another argument instead “value” for example “slug” or “name”?
If not, how can modify the call to show only value without link?

Thank’s

Answer (score 3):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php -

```
function filter_woocommerce_attribute_value( $value ) { 
    return preg_replace( '#<a.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i', '$1', $value );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute', 'filter_woocommerce_attribute_value', 99 );
```